# Oracle Apex - create timestamp with time

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-apex

I'm creating a form in Apex.  One of my fields is a timestamp.  Apex puts in a datepicker, which is great, but I want to store a time as well.

What's the best way of doing this?  Can I have 2 separate boxes printed, one for the date and one for the time?

Comment: Application Express 4.0.2.00.07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it should have been easy.  For the record, you just give your date picker a format mask that includes the time and it adds time selector to the date picker.